# Hover and selected state for an image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Hei, Here is my code:

```
<img id="body_image" usemap="#body_map" src="assets/images/body.jpg" alt="">

<map name="body_map">
   <area shape="poly" alt="d" href="#body_chart" name="ad" coords="153, 153, 145, 164, 150, 175, 163, 165, 163, 157" />
</map>
```

Now I need to add a hover and selected state for the map area. Also I want to make more area and multiple selection at a time.

Now can you please help me by writing the whole code for hover and selected state.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JQuery version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#location-map')) {
        $('#location-map area').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).mouseover(function() {
                $('#overlay'+id).show();

            });

            $(this).mouseout(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#overlay'+id).hide();
            });

        });
    }
});
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It will not help for my project. I just need a border around the area.

Comment: Do you wanna take away an existing border, or add a border?